# Follow Active Quads doesn't align the ends of UV properly

Tags: uv

I am trying to UV unwrap the face of a cylinder so the texture creates concentric rings on the surface. However I can't get the UV map to properly align the "ends" and instead always distorts at one of the edges. I have used the "Follow Active Quads" command and even tried the reset trick that some users have mentioned.

Any help would be much appreciated. TIA

[image]

Comment: maybe it has to do with the Subdivision Surface modifier, in its Advanced options make sure it is set to Boundary > Keep Corners?

Comment: Aha! Yes, that was it. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, in its *Advanced* options make sure it is set to *Boundary > Keep Corners*.